# How to custom django-filter form?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filter

How to custom `django-filter` form? I want add `onChange="form.submit();"` for auto submiting and to set labels in template. When I tried to use `{{ filter.age_filter }}` in template it doesn't show anything.

My filter:

```
class EventFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    AGE_CHOICES = (
        ('18+', '18+'),
        ('19+', '19+'),
        ('21+', '21+'),
    )

    age_filter = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(label='Age Limit', 
    choices=AGE_CHOICES, method='filter_by_age')


    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = {'title': ['icontains']}

    def filter_by_age(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(age_limit=value)
```

My template:

```
<form  method="get" >
            {{ filter.form}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn- 
primary">Filter</button>
</form>
```